# Custom WebService + FBA = 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: 2010, web-services, access-denied

I've created custom web service in Sharepoint 2010, and custom FBA. I try to connect from a Win Forms app on another computer.

1/ I log into with cookie container (Authentication.Login)

2/ I call the custom web service with same cookie container

In the web service, `SPUser myUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;` is ok. But every other operation throw Access Denied error... :

```
'SPContext.Current.Web.AllowAnonymousAccess' a levé une exception de type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
```

I get this even if my user is granted for full access.

What can be wrong?

**Edit:** same problem when I call standard Web Service, `like Lists.GetList(name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean install and everything is ok now.